# How to represent Java varargs in a UML static class diagram?

Tags: java, uml, variadic-functions

I'm creating a UML static class diagram for [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).  How should I denote [doInBackground(Params... params)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground%28Params...%29), which has a variable number of argumetns?

Comment: Using `Params[]` wouldn't be very wrong.

Comment: Since varargs is syntactic sugar for an array, you can use an array instead

Comment: Even though an array can't be passed as the argument?

Comment: An array *can* be passed as argument. varargs is compiler syntactic sugar for an array. See http://ideone.com/gfm86S

Comment: I hadn't realized that.  Thank you for correcting me.  Should I delete the question or let one of you provide the answer?

Comment: @fge, could you state that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I'd rather @JBNizet posted his and you accept his, since he made the effort to write some demo code...

Comment: @fge: I already have had 350 points today. Post an answer, and feel free to steal my code if you want to.

Comment: @JBNizet OK, then... And sorry...

Comment: What a display of politeness!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so, first, apologies to @JBNizet for blatant code stealing (original URL to the stolen code: [here](http://ideone.com/gfm86S)).

The thing is that Java 5's varargs is just syntactic sugar for an array. Witness this code:

```
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        foo(args);
    }

    private static void foo(String... params) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(params));
    }
}
```

It works. It would have worked the same if instead you had used a varargs in `main()` and an array in `foo()`.

So, in UML, you can model varargs as an array.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK UML does not allow to do so. But if you look from the other side: varargs in Java is just an Array of objects. I believe from modeling perspective this should not make any differene.